# Checking whether a number of vectors exist in a matrix, need speed

Tags: r, performance, matrix

I have two large numerical matrices and need to check which rows in one of them exist in the other one (exist as in being equal). This is my code:

```
myMatrix1 <- rbind(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6),c(7,8,9))
myMatrix2 <- rbind(c(10,11,12),c(4,5,6),c(13,14,15))

logicalMatrix <- apply(myMatrix1,1,checkForEquality)
result <- apply(logicalMatrix,1,any)

checkForEquality <- function(x){
  apply(myMatrix2, 1, innerFcn, oneRow = x)
}
innerFcn <- function(x, oneRow){
  isTRUE(all.equal(x, oneRow))
}
```

result is

```
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

With two 2067*198 matrices this takes 350 seconds on my machine. With CPU-parallelization I guess I could bring it down to around 15 seconds. Unfortunately anything above 1 second is unacceptable. I need some direction. The matrices contain only 0's, 1's and 2's, if that matters.

Comment: Of all the base methods I tend to use to determine "sameness", `all.equal` is the slowest. Consider replacing `all.equal(x,y)` with `all(x==y)`. Especially since you need a simple true/false returned, once `all.equal` finds they are not equal, comparison is still made to some extend in order to report the differences. It seems you really want a short-circuit operation, not a "report to me all of the differences".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use euclidean distance, which can be expressed as vectorized/linear algebra operations:

```
dist_xy <- outer(rowSums(x^2), rowSums(y^2), '+') - tcrossprod(x, 2 * y))
```

Benchmark:

```
nr = 1e5
nc = 200
x = t(sample(0:2, size = nc, replace = TRUE))
y = matrix(sample(0L:2L, size = nc * nr, replace = TRUE), nrow = nr)

all.equal(apply(y, 1, function(z) identical(z, x)),
          drop(outer(rowSums(x^2), rowSums(y^2), '+') == tcrossprod(x, 2 * y)))
# [1] TRUE

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  A = apply(y, 1, function(z) identical(z, x)),
  B = apply(y, 1, function(z) all(z == x)),
  C = drop(outer(rowSums(x^2), rowSums(y^2), '+') == tcrossprod(x, 2 * y)),
  times = 3
)
Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
    A 543.1362 559.9647 585.3627 576.7931 606.4760 636.1589     3
    B 609.7400 636.5922 667.3405 663.4445 696.1408 728.8370     3
    C 368.2808 416.4194 441.9118 464.5580 478.7273 492.8965     3
```

This should benefits even more if you have larger matrices.

Comment: I'm really surprised this is faster than the `identical` or `all( == )` methods - do you have intuition why this is the case?

Comment: I've tried your example (C) and in reality it's way faster than the others because you can apply it to the whole matrix at once. With one 2067*198 matrix and the other a 6201*198 matrix it's about 15x faster than identical(). You only used one vector (x) in your example. Anyway, it's still not fast enough and I will attempt to do the same thing with GPU-parallelization.

Comment: Yeah, linear algebra is just fast, especially if you link R with some fast matrix library, such as OpenBLAS or MKL.

Answer (score 2):

Calculate the distance matrix:

```
X <- rbind(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6),c(7,8,9))
Y <- rbind(c(10,11,12),c(4,5,6),c(13,14,15))

library(pracma)
ind <- which(distmat(X, Y) == 0L, arr.ind = TRUE)
#     row col
#[1,]   2   2

X[ind[, 1],]
#[1] 4 5 6

Y[ind[, 2],]
#[1] 4 5 6
```

If you need to consider floating point accuracy, use this:

```
ind <- which(abs(distmat(X, Y)) < tol, arr.ind = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a roughly 10x speedup by switching away from `all.equal`. `all(x == y)` and `pracma::distmat`, and `identical(x, y)` are all about 10x faster, with  `identical(x, y)` as the fastest (note: this is for comparisons of length 200, as in your data. For longer vectors, `all(x == y)` may be faster!).

```
# sample data
## demo on single row vs matrix comparison
nr = 1e5
nc = 200
x = sample(0:2, size = nc, replace = TRUE)
y = matrix(sample(0L:2L, size = nc * nr, replace = TRUE), nrow = nr)


library(pracma)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  apply(y, 1, function(z) identical(z, x)),
  apply(y, 1, function(z) all(z == x)),
  apply(y, 1, function(z) all.equal(z, x)),
  which(distmat(x, y) == 0L, arr.ind = TRUE),
  times = 2
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#                                        expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max
#    apply(y, 1, function(z) identical(z, x))  619.1912  619.1912  644.3034  644.3034  669.4156  669.4156
#        apply(y, 1, function(z) all(z == x))  759.4982  759.4982  789.4765  789.4765  819.4548  819.4548
#    apply(y, 1, function(z) all.equal(z, x)) 7618.6853 7618.6853 7657.7665 7657.7665 7696.8477 7696.8477
#  which(distmat(x, y) == 0L, arr.ind = TRUE)  824.8337  824.8337  899.2349  899.2349  973.6360  973.6360
```

You could obviously go faster with Rcpp, but even doing row-wise comparisons in a `for` loop will be pretty quick in R (thanks to JIT compilation).

The next spot I'd try to optimize would be early stopping - if you find match, you don't need to check any more comparisons with that row, so you can go on to the next row. You can't do this well with `apply`, but with a `for` loop you have greater control.

Comment: With larger vectors, `all(x==y)` surpasses `identical` in performance.

Comment: @r2evans interesting and good to know -- I wonder why that is. I'll add that caveat to the answer.

Comment: Note that a comparison algorithm could be applied only to row clusters whose rowSums are equal.  Squaring the terms in the matrix and then taking the rowSums would reduce the common row count further.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract b from a and then find take the rowSum of the absolute values in case the positive and negative differences cancel out.  The zero sum rows will be identical:

```
diff <- a - b
idrows <- rowSum(abs(diff))
```

Comment: You are making the assumption that it would be the same row in both matrices that is equal. That's not how I read the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just try:

```
asplit(m2,1) %in% asplit(m1,1)
```

An example with some medium matrices:

```
dims<-c(1920,198)
set.seed(4)
m1<-matrix(sample(0:2,prod(dims),TRUE),ncol=dims[2])
m2<-matrix(sample(0:2,prod(dims),TRUE),ncol=dims[2])
#simulate some rows in m2 which are equal to some rows in m1
samind<-sample(nrow(m1),50)
samind2<-sample(nrow(m2),50)
m2[samind2,]<-m1[samind,]
system.time(res<-asplit(m2,1) %in% asplit(m1,1))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.407   0.000   0.406
#Check whether the result is correct
identical(which(res),sort(samind2))
#[1] TRUE
```